# How to handle a case like calling a method in Component A from method in component B in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to pass a course label form `Component #1` to `Component #2`.I tried to achieve this by calling a method in another component.But it failed saying `Reference Error occurred`. How to achieve this?

Component #1:

```
var CourseCard = React.createClass({
  showPapers: function(){
    console.log("Clicked:" + this.props.each_course.label);
    setCourseName(this.props.each_course.label);
    var elem = React.createElement(Papers, {
      course : this.props.each_course.label
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return(
      <Link to="/papers">
        <div className="course_card" onClick={this.showPapers}>
          <img className="course_img" src={this.props.each_course.image}/>
          <h4>{this.props.each_course.label}</h4>
        </div>
      </Link>
      );
  }
});
```

Component #2:

```
const Papers = React.createClass({
  setCourseName: function(course_name){
    console.log("Called setCourseName with name" + course_name);
  },
  render () {
    return (
        <h1>List of all papers</h1>
      )
  }
})
```

Comment: Component #2 looks like it is on a different page. I would pass a query string in the `Link` component.

Comment: How do we pass parameters with `Link` ?

Comment: Using this way we cannot get the value of label.It displays {this.props.label} in url.And is there any other method with out getting value from URL again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080102/react-router-passing-data-through-routes This may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) to call a method of another component.

Component #1

```
var CourseCard = React.createClass({
  showPapers(){
    console.log("Clicked:" + this.props.each_course.label);
    this.refs.papers.setCourseName(this.props.each_course.label);
  },    
  render() {
    return(
      <Link to="/papers">
        <div className="course_card" onClick={this.showPapers}>
          <img className="course_img" src={this.props.each_course.image}/>
          <h4>{this.props.each_course.label}</h4>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Papers refs="papers"/>
    );
  }
});
```

Component #2

```
const Papers = React.createClass({
  setCourseName(course_name){
    console.log("Called setCourseName with name" + course_name);
  },
  render () {
    return <h1>List of all papers</h1>;
  }
})
```

But try to avoid it as much as possible and use props instead of calling a method of component directly.